# Logout user after three unsuccesfull attempts - ASP.NET

Tags: c#, asp.net, authentication

I am new to programming. In my web application, user will receive a popup alert when he attempts to access restricted page. After three unsuccessful attempts i want him to be logged-out(i.e redirect to logout page). My question is, how to capture each failed attempts.

My existing code for giving alerts,

```cs
protected override void OnInit(EventArgs e)
{
    base.OnInit(e);
    if (Convert.ToString(Session["StaffID"]) != "1" || Convert.ToString(Session["StaffID"]) == null || Convert.ToString(Session["StaffID"]) == "")
    {
        Response.Write("<script language='javascript'>window.alert('You are not allowed to view this page');window.location='Mainpage.aspx';</script>");
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can capture each failed attemped by using another session . Please check below code. I am test this in ASP.NET MVC. Session["StaffID"] is your condition check or any condition so use another session to count attempt. Hope it will help you.

```
    public ActionResult OnInit()
    {
        base.OnInit(e);
        var accessCount = Convert.ToInt16(Session["AccessCount"]);
        if (Convert.ToString(Session["StaffID"]) != "1" || Convert.ToString(Session["StaffID"]) == null || Convert.ToString(Session["StaffID"]) == "")
        {
            //Response.Write("<script language='javascript'>window.alert('You are not allowed to view this page');window.location='Mainpage.aspx';</script>");
            accessCount++;
            if (accessCount <= 3)
            {
                Session["AccessCount"] = accessCount;
                return Content("<script>alert('You are not allowed to view this page')</script>");
            }
            else
            {
                Session["AccessCount"] = 0;
                return RedirectToAction("logout");
            }
        }
    }
```